# How to pass a javascript array in an html file to another html file in django and also redirect to the new html file

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, django-templates

```
 var resulttable = "<table border=1>";
    resulttable += "<tr>";
        resulttable += "<th>"+heading1+"</th>";
        resulttable += "<th>"+heading2+"</th>";
        resulttable += "<th>"+heading3+"</th>";
        resulttable += "<th>"+heading4+"</th>";
    resulttable += "</tr>";
    for(var i=0; i<angles.length; i++) {
        resulttable += "<tr>";
            resulttable += "<td>"+angles[i]+"</td>";
            resulttable += "<td>"+expert_angle[i]+"</td>";
            resulttable += "<td>"+user_angle[i]+"</td>";
            resulttable += "<td>"+diff[i]+"</td>";

        resulttable += "</tr>";
    }
```

Above is the javascript string in an html file. I want to pass this string into another another html file and display its contents to the user. I cant display it in the current page as it already has many contents. I want to know how to pass the javascript array to another file and how to redirect to the new html file after passing of the string

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please provide your other html files?

Comment: The current html file in which the above js array is created is really big but only this array will be its final result and I want to send it to another html page just to print it.

Comment: I dont think full code of html files will be necessary.

Comment: Ok so in which action you want to pass this array to another html file for print?

Comment: this array is created as a result of a function which is triggered via a click of a button, so after the creating of the array I want to pass it to another html file as a part of the existing function itself and also redirect to the new html file

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, but it is an Idea!
send this js array with AJAX or any other tool, but like a form with one input text field to the backend, to a views.py function
inside that function you're able to take the text, and again pass it to a new html file and render.

```
<form id="js-table-form" method="post"  action="{% url 'js-table' %}" >
     <input type="hidden" id="js-table-holder" name="tablejs" />
</form>
<a href="javascript:{}" id="js-form-submit" > click here! </a>
<script>
    $("#js-form-submit").on('click', function (){
        $("#js-table-holder").val(" here must be your table data ");
        $("#js-table-form").send();
   });
</script>
```

in urls.py -> urlpatterns:

```
path('js-table', views.js_table, name="js-table")
```

in views.py:

```
def js_table(request):
    table = str()
    if request.method == 'POST':
         table = request.POST.get('tablejs') # the hidden inputs name attribute value!
    return render (request, "table_page.html", {"table": table})
```

in table_page.html:

```
{{ table|safe }}
```

you could catch every part of the table in an input field separately and then again in the last template rebuild the table part by part